# VBA unable to change pivot cache

Tags: excel, vba

Hi my code below isn't working. It seemed to work yesterday and I am now getting a type mismatch. Any ideas? Error line is the last line when actually attempting to change the source.

```
Dim IRDatabaseToUse As String
Dim Pt As PivotTable
Dim IRwb As Workbook
Dim IRRange As Range

Set IRwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=IRDatabaseToUse, ReadOnly:=True)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    LRow = IRwb.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set IRRange = Workbooks(Dir(IRDatabaseToUse)).Sheets("Data").Range("A1:O" & LRow)

Pivots.PivotTables("IRDatabase1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=IRRange)
```

Comment: What's the error and what line is causing it?

Comment: Just edited the question. It's the last line, everything else works fine

Comment: Can you `debug.print` the address of the `IRange`, I doubt it is the problem?

Comment: Debug.print IRRange.Address gives $A$1:$O$480633 which is the range I want but it doesn't refer to the actual workbook. Could that be the issue? Still don't really get why it's giving a type mismatch though

Comment: a type mismatch happens when you'ring assigning two incompatible types to each other.

Comment: Yes I know but I've set it as a range and the source data requires a range so it shouldn't be a type mismatch

Comment: Try this `set IRRange = Workbooks(Dir(IRDatabaseToUse)).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:O" & LRow)`

Comment: That's exactly what I've already got???

Comment: You code seems legit. Check your `Dir` function. If not, there must be  merged cells somewhere in your worksheet that is causing the `Lastrow` ro fail.

Comment: The Dir function is fine and the LRow isn't failing so it can't be those. There's also definitely no merged cells

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

Changed the last couple lines of code because I assumed that the IRRange might not be referring to the right sheet. Seems to have worked for now.

```
Set IRRange = IRwb.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:O" & LRow)

x = "'[IR Database 2014.xlsb]Data'!" & IRRange.Address

Pivots.PivotTables("IRDatabase1").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=x)
```